# Twilio: Unmute a participant that have been muted when entering the conference

Tags: android, twilio

I use the attribute `muted=true` to mute all participants joining a conference like it's described here

https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/conference#attributes-muted

It works and all participants are muted. Now I wonder how to allow each user to individually unmute using the Twilio Voice SDK on Android.

It weird because when receiving the call, `call.isMuted` is `false` even if the call is muted. Then, when trying to unmute the call with `call.mute(false)` nothing happens and the call is still muted.

When muting a participant via the conference TWIML, there is no way to unmute it later? Is there a way for each participant to know if he has been muted? And if yes, how he can unmute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

You can use the [conference participants API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/conference-participant) for that.

```
    Participant participant = Participant.updater(
            "CFXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
            "CAXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
        .setMuted(true).update();
```

The docs implement several resources with code examples on how to [mute](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/conference-participant?code-sample=code-update-mute-a-participant&code-language=Node.js&code-sdk-version=3.x) or do other actions with participants.

Hope that helps. :)

Comment: Thanks. It helps. I'll see how to implement it.